# Towards the complex unit conjecture

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

After Gardam had found a counterexample to the Kaplansky unit conjecture for the group ring $K[G]$ with $K = \mathbf F_2$ and $G = P$, the [Promislow group](https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/20/4/302/285006?redirectedFrom=PDF), [Murray extended this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.02147.pdf) to $\mathbf{F}_p[P]$ for all primes. Of course, it would be great to refute the conjecture in the complex case too but the proof methods are susceptible to positive characteristic.

However, I can prove using standard model-theoretic trickery that if for all (or at least infinitely many) primes we could get examples of non-trivial units in $\mathbf{F}_p[P]$ whose supports have uniformly bounded cardinalities, then one can cook up a complex counterexample.

The problem is that the counterexamples found by Murray lack this property as they contain the factor $(1-(ab)^2)^{p-2}$ where $a, b$ are the standard generators of $P$. So I would like to get my head around it:

> Are there any obvious obstacles preventing the existence of non-trivial units in $\mathbf{F}_p[G]$ whose supports have uniformly bounded cardinality regardless of $p$?

Comment: Isn’t it the case that any non-trivial unit in the group ring over $\mathbb{Z}$ would reduce to such a unit for all but finitely many $p$? If so, then it seems like a positive answer to your question would be close to a proof of the unit conjecture for $\mathbb{Z}[P]$.

Comment: The short answer is no, there isn't. You are indeed right that bounded support as $p$ grows is exactly what is needed to solve this problem, at least over something like $\mathbb{Q}$, if not over $\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 9):

There are no such obstacles *a posteriori* since the complex unit conjecture is [false](https://arxiv.org/abs/2312.05240).